# Azure Table Storage continuation token lifetime

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

How long I could keep continuation token between queries?
Is continuation token persists when some entity deleted from or added to the table?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand about continuation token is that it is a marker which if used in a query against table storage will return next set of results from that marker. If I'm not mistaken, you could keep these tokens as long as you want however there's no guarantee that same results will be returned. For example, if new entities are added or some old entities are deleted then you may get different set of result back. Furthermore, table storage service keeps on rearranging the data. If that happens, even though you have not added/removed any entities you may get different set of result back.